# How do I access the "The Secret Armory of General Knoxx"?

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-secret-armory-of-knoxx

I have been playing Borderlands for a little bit, and I heard about "[The Secret Armory of General Knoxx](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Secret_Armory_of_General_Knoxx)", so I purchased and downloaded the DLC. The first time, it would not download, but after another attempt, I have been told that it as downloaded successfully.

The only problem is, I can not find the content, in game.

How do I start "The Secret Armory of General Knoxx"?

Comment: do you mean the dlc?

Answer (score 3):

As with all the DLC expansions from Borderlands, The Secret Armory of General Knoxx is accessed through the quick-travel system.

All you have to do is locate your nearest quick travel, and travel to [T-Bone Junction](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/T-Bone_Junction), the DLC starting area.

Keep in mind that there is some assumption<sup>1</sup> that the player has completed the main game. If you have not, you can still access the new area, but scaling can be rather particular. It might be a breeze, it might be a death walk<sup>2</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> It is clear, from introductory dialogue, that the DLC is designed to take place **after** the opening of the vault, however, you should not have a problem accessing the DLC prior to completing the main game.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Not sure how the scale works, but I was able to roll through the Halloween DLC as a brand new level 1 character, only to have a level 10 character stopped in the first area. IIRC, the armory was more difficult, in terms of scaling to the player's level.</sub>